# Changing url with .htaccess loses content

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am making a simple CMS, so the page links are `domain/index.php?page=1` and so on (page2, page3...), and I am pulling the content out of the database with the following line:

```
$q = "SELECT name, content FROM pages WHERE page_id=$page";
```

That all works, but I wanted to change the look of the URLs, so I did with the following in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)/?$    index.php?page=$1    [NC,L]
```

The problem is, now when I click on the page I changed the url (in this case it was ?page=2), I don't pull the content out of the db, I guess because the MySQL query cant find `$page`

How do I remedy this?

**EDIT:**

I updated the rule to include numeric characters as well but it is still the same.

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$    index.php?page=$1    [NC,L]
```

**EDIT2:**

Just to hammer the point home, if I for example hardcode `page=2` in the rewrite rule it works, but obviously I want that to happen dynamically. In this case `$1` should become `2`.

Comment: echo  your query and run in  `phpmyadmin`

Comment: What is the URL in the browser that you're using to test this?

Comment: http://mydomain/index.php?page=2

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure

```
$q = "SELECT name, content FROM pages WHERE page_id=$page";
```

is directly taken from your code? It has a few quite severe problems:

- You probably (and rightfully so) do not have `register_globals` enabled. So `$page` should actually be `$_GET['page']`.
- Your query is prone to attacks, you should always `mysql_real_escape_string()` parameters going into your queries.
- A user could enter non-numeric values. Those would not be catched but would probably end up in syntax errors.

My advice? There is no point in writing all this stuff yourself. Instead use an existing modern CMS or framework. 99% of the mistakes and security holes you'd end up creating have been taken into account in them already.

Comment: Can you show me how to add [QSA] ? I am not too comfortable with htaccess

Comment: Regarding my "use a framework" point: Nobody is creating websites in Ruby alone. Instead, they are using Ruby on Rails. You should do the same. Pick for example Laravel; it culminates all the most recent awesome advancements in the PHP language and community and is a please to use.

Comment: I am aware of some holes, this is for learning purposes. Anyway, $page of course already equals $_GET['page_id'] , the point is that the htaccess doesnt read in the number after "=" . If I hardcode it it works, but not as it is.

Comment: `$_GET['page_id']` or `$_GET['page']`? See wich one would be correct? You should **always** take the exact code you have in your scripts.

Comment: That is not the problem, it is page_id, I never even mentioned that, you did. The code is valid the problem is the mod rewriting.

Comment: But `$_GET['page_id']` is **WRONG**.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. $page = $_GET['page']. I also have page_id somewhere in the page so i got confused. Anyway as I said the PHP is fine, it all updates nice, the problem is the urls.